# Этимология слова "Пришелец" (в значении инопланетный пришелец, космический пришелец)

Tags: этимология

Собственно вопрос:
Почему именно "пришелец", когда логичнее подходит, допустим "прилетелец"?
Или почему прилепилось данное слово к чему-то инопланетному, прилетевшему из космического пространства?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Пришелец](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%86) здесь означает «тот, кто недавно впервые пришёл, прибыл куда-либо» либо «чужой». Устаревшая форма слова [пришлец](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%86), также означает «чужой».

Соответственно, речь идет о чужом человеке/существе, а не о способе его передвижения.

Слово употреблялось и употребляется для людей пришлых, иностранцев/чужеземцев:

> *Афанасий Ананьев «Сокращенный латинский словарь», 1862*
>   advena, ae, m и f. (advenire) 1) **пришелец**, иноземец, иностранец, пришлый, иностранный о людях, животных и вещах.
>
> *А.Н. Муравьев «Русская Фиваида на Севере»,  1855*
>   Так умилительно и благоговейно совершалось сие вечернее, христианское прощение пастыря с его паствою, что никто даже не заметил присутствия чуждого лица, хотя я был один только **пришелец** в церкви, совершенно пустой; признаюсь, это благочестивое зрелище тронуло меня до слез, напомнив мне Афонские пустынные скиты.

В том же значении слово употребляется для космических пришельцев. Нечто похожее произошло в английском языке с alien.

Comment: Сопоставление "пришелец" = "чужой", это однозначная победа в разных вариантах, в ответах! Спасибо.

Comment: Добавлю, что термин "пришелец", в данном понимании, актуален скорее только для Земли или освоенного анклава\планеты. В космосе, по отношению к живущим там, пришельцами являемся мы.

Answer (score 1):

**Из словаря:**

ПРИЙТИ, 3. **Достичь места назначения**.

**Прийти ― многозначное слово,** одним из его значений является "достичь определенного места в пространстве".  В данном случае инопланетяне **достигли Земли**, поэтому они пришельцы. А каким образом они это сделали (прилетели, телепортировались и т.д.)  ― нам неважно.

Answer (score 0):

как минимум в нашем представлении инопланетные существа обладают конечностями. Соответственно, после прибытия на нашу планету они передвигаются. Условимся, что они ходят и слово "Пришелец" употребляется в значении "тот, кто недавно впервые пришёл, прибыл куда-либо".

Answer (score 0):

Большой толковый словарь:
ПРИШЕЛЕЦ, -льца; м. 1. Существо из другого мира, с другой планеты; инопланетянин. П. из космоса. Установить контакт с пришельцами. 2. Пришлый, не местный человек. Пришельцы из далёкого аула. Усталый п. Лесной п. (о звере, пришедшем к жилью).

Ни одно из приведенных значений не преполагает передвижения пешком. Хотя  корень, наверное, свидетельствует о том, что в далеком прошлом передвижение "на своих двоих" было главным способом перемещения.